# To many For statements causing memory issues

Tags: python, iterable

I'm getting a Memory error in Python, this isn't surprising, but I need an alternative. So I'm using several for satements which to my knowledge store the values in memory. What should I switch the for statements to so they save it to something that won't save to memory. Would saving it to a text file be a better route? The code is below to help answer what I should do. I'd like examples of any of your ideas.

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)

def start():
    for chars in product("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12234567890!@#$%^&*?,()-=+[]/;", repeat = 4):
        print chars
```

Comment: We _just told you_ to use `itertools.product` in your last question. That's the code from the docs, __not__ the real `itertools.product`. I think the docs make that pretty clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

def start():
    for chars in product("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12234567890!@#$%^&*?,()-=+[]/;", repeat = 4):
        print chars
```

From the documentation:

> This function is equivalent to the following code, except that the actual implementation **does not build up intermediate results in memory**

Comment: This has the advantage of being implemented C-side, so very efficient, and less work.

Comment: That's so weird, I thought I was. Thanks for this!

Comment: This isn't really part of the question but would printing each result slow down the calculation?

Comment: @NoahR: Printing results will certainly slow down your program. I/O is one of the slowest things you can do with a computer.

Comment: Thanks Mark, you've helped a lot!